# JSON decoding failing when using var instead of let

Tags: json, swift

Here is my Swift code:

```swift
import Foundation

func load<T: Codable>() -> T? {
    let data: Data
    let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main.json", withExtension: nil)
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl!)
    } catch {
        fatalError("error getting data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
     
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("error decoding: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

@Observable
class Mordor: Codable {
    var id: Int
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Inside another view:

```swift
let m: Mordor? = load()
```

Getting error:

> error decoding: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

But when I use `let` instead of `var` on the `Mordor` class, it is working.

Comment: when you get the error, can you also print the decoded value of `data` ?

Comment: The new Observation types don’t behave well with Codable, they have a different implementation than you would expect.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77697483/5133585

Comment: Unrelated but you don’t really need a generic function since you are reading and decoding a hardcoded file. And there is nowhere the function returns nil so you don’t need an optional return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Based on [this article](https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2023/08/14/new-swift-observation/). It looks like there are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Manually implement the Codable protocol.
2. Provide coding keys to satisfy conformance to Codable.

Note - When using `Observable` all stored properties have been transformed into computed properties which have shadow stored properties prefixed by _ (id becomes _id, name becomes _name, etc)

Thus it would be sufficient to just add the coding keys like this:

```
import Foundation
import Observation

@Observable
class Mordor: Codable {
    var id: Int

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case _id = "id"
    }
}
```

As pointed out in the comments by [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) the other solution is to implement `required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {` manually. Autocomplete actually wrote this and the encode function for me. It should look like this.

```
@Observable
class Mordor: Codable {
    var id: Int

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id
        case _$observationRegistrar
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.id, forKey: .id)
        // Auto complete added the line below but it doesn't appear to be required.
        // try container.encode(self._$observationRegistrar, forKey: ._$observationRegistrar)
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s a bit strange that you encode two properties but only decode one.

Comment: Agreed. [This post](https://forums.swift.org/t/composition-of-codable-and-observable/66766) provides some insight with the message warning "Immutable property will not be decoded because it is declared with an initial value which cannot be overwritten". Perhaps it's encoded by autocomplete simply for completeness? I removed that portion of the encoding and the encoding and decoding still works as expected so I don't think it's required.